# Javascript call vairable outcome outside function? Not defined?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I have the following code.

```
var myDatepicker = $('#datumpak').datepicker({
onSelect: function (formattedDate, date, inst) {
    if (date.length == 2) {
        Jaar = ("0" + date[0].getFullYear()).slice(-4);
        Maand = ("0" + (date[0].getMonth()+1)).slice(-2); 
        Dag = ("0" + date[0].getDate()).slice(-2);
        Uren = ("0" + date[0].getHours()).slice(-2); 
        Minuut = ("0" + date[0].getMinutes()).slice(-2); 
        Seconden = ("0" + date[0].getSeconds()).slice(-2);  
        var totaaldatea = (Jaar) + (Maand) + (Dag) + (Uren) + (Minuut) + (Seconden);

        Jaar1 = ("0" + date[1].getFullYear()).slice(-4);
        Maand1 = ("0" + (date[1].getMonth()+1)).slice(-2); 
        Dag1 = ("0" + date[1].getDate()).slice(-2);
        Uren1 = ("0" + date[1].getHours()).slice(-2); 
        Minuut1 = ("0" + date[1].getMinutes()).slice(-2); 
        Seconden1 = ("0" + date[1].getSeconds()).slice(-2);  
        var totaaldateb = (Jaar1) + (Maand1) + (Dag1) + (Uren1) + (Minuut1) + (Seconden1);
        }
    }}).data('datepicker');
// Console.log(totaaldatea) NOT WORKING!?
```

Why can't i call the variable outside the function and how do i need to solve this? Please help.

Comment: Mostly because you tried to log it before anyone selected a date in the datepicker, and also because the `var` is declared local to the `onSelect` function. Why not just move the `console.log` inside the function?

Comment: I'd suggest read about javascript scopes.

Comment: @Bergi, because i need the outcome of the variable into another function, which don't need the onclick thing.

Comment: @TimvanHeteren Please show that other function and where/how it is called, then.

Answer (score 0):

Your variable is out of scope. You should define the variable, then change it:

```
var totaaldatea;  // Declare the variables outside the function.
var totaaldateb;

var myDatepicker = $('#datumpak').datepicker({
onSelect: function (formattedDate, date, inst) {
    if (date.length == 2) {
        var Jaar = ("0" + date[0].getFullYear()).slice(-4);
        var Maand = ("0" + (date[0].getMonth()+1)).slice(-2); 
        var Dag = ("0" + date[0].getDate()).slice(-2);
        var Uren = ("0" + date[0].getHours()).slice(-2); 
        var Minuut = ("0" + date[0].getMinutes()).slice(-2); 
        var Seconden = ("0" + date[0].getSeconds()).slice(-2);  
        totaaldatea = (Jaar) + (Maand) + (Dag) + (Uren) + (Minuut) + (Seconden); // change it inside

        var Jaar1 = ("0" + date[1].getFullYear()).slice(-4);
        var Maand1 = ("0" + (date[1].getMonth()+1)).slice(-2); 
        var Dag1 = ("0" + date[1].getDate()).slice(-2);
        var Uren1 = ("0" + date[1].getHours()).slice(-2); 
        var Minuut1 = ("0" + date[1].getMinutes()).slice(-2); 
        var Seconden1 = ("0" + date[1].getSeconds()).slice(-2);  
        totaaldateb = (Jaar1) + (Maand1) + (Dag1) + (Uren1) + (Minuut1) + (Seconden1); // change it inside
        }
    }}).data('datepicker');
// Console.log(totaaldatea)
```

If you're not using your variables outside the function, just log the values inside, like:

```
var myDatepicker = $('#datumpak').datepicker({
  onSelect: function (formattedDate, date, inst) {
    if (date.length == 2) {
      var Jaar = ("0" + date[0].getFullYear()).slice(-4);
      var Maand = ("0" + (date[0].getMonth()+1)).slice(-2); 
      var Dag = ("0" + date[0].getDate()).slice(-2);
      var Uren = ("0" + date[0].getHours()).slice(-2); 
      var Minuut = ("0" + date[0].getMinutes()).slice(-2); 
      var Seconden = ("0" + date[0].getSeconds()).slice(-2);  
      var totaaldatea = (Jaar) + (Maand) + (Dag) + (Uren) + (Minuut) + (Seconden);
      console.log(totaaldatea)

      var Jaar1 = ("0" + date[1].getFullYear()).slice(-4);
      var Maand1 = ("0" + (date[1].getMonth()+1)).slice(-2); 
      var Dag1 = ("0" + date[1].getDate()).slice(-2);
      var Uren1 = ("0" + date[1].getHours()).slice(-2); 
      var Minuut1 = ("0" + date[1].getMinutes()).slice(-2); 
      var Seconden1 = ("0" + date[1].getSeconds()).slice(-2);  
      var totaaldateb = (Jaar1) + (Maand1) + (Dag1) + (Uren1) + (Minuut1) + (Seconden1);
      console.log(totaaldateb)
    }
  }
}).data('datepicker');
```

Comment: Don't forget `totaldataa` too

Comment: Thanks - didn't realise they were different vars!

Comment: Don't forget to declare *all* these variables.

Comment: How is that possible @AndyMardell?

Comment: You're probably logging the variable before you've run the function which populates it. I have updated my answer - as it sounds like you don't need the variables to be global. Maybe. Idk

Comment: As @Bergi said - all your variables (Jaar1 etc) were declared wrong, as well

Answer (score 0):

@Bergi

```
var postData;
    function showroute() {
        voertuiglijstsource.clear();
        var postData = {
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Easytrack/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Easytrack%3AFilter_compleet&outputFormat=application%2Fjson&viewparams=code:' + $('#selectvoertuig').val().replace(' ', '%20') // + outcome totaldatea and totaldateb
        };    
            console.log(postData); 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'php/geoproxycurl.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: postData,
            method: 'post'
        }).done(function (data) {
            voertuiglijstsource.addFeatures(new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(data, {
                dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
                featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
            }));
        });
    }
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59663771/edit) to include more information, don't post it as an answer

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript has two scopes – **global** and **local**. Any variable declared outside of a function belongs to the **global** scope, and is therefore accessible from anywhere in your code. Each function has its own scope, and any variable declared within that function is only accessible from that function and any nested functions.

your variable `totaaldatea` has local scope,but you call it in a global scope-for this reason it gives that **error** message

Comment: @bergi share some scope name-definition,even if you have any link,share with us.